# Python: ASCII letters slicing and concatenation

Tags: python, string, ascii, concatenation, slice

I am trying to cut 3 letters from the start of the alphabet and put it at the end but I am getting an odd result. This is my code so far...

```
import string

upper = string.ascii_uppercase
upperNew = upper[:3] + upper[3:]
print upperNew

a = upper[:3]
b = upper[3:]
c = b+a
print c
```

Running this code gets:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
```

Why doesn't print upperNew yield the same result as print c?

Comment: Because the order is different, do `c = a + b`.

Comment: Try `upperNew = upper[3:] + upper[:3]`

Comment: Don't you mean `c = a + b`?

Comment: Yeah, upperNew is just doing the concatenation backwards, resulting in no change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the ":" notation for the lists.

- `upper[:3]` gives the *first* 3 characters from upper whereas
- `upper[3:]` gives you the whole list *but* the 3 first characters.

In the end you end up with :

```
upperNew = upper[:3] + upper[3:]  
         = 'ABC'     + 'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

When you sum them into `upperNew`, you get the alphabet.

It happens the same thing the second time in `a` and `b`, but you concatenate them in the reversed order, so you get `'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' + 'ABC'+` which is probably why you seem confused.

If you want `upperNew` to give the same result, you have to do it this way :

```
upperNew = upper[3:] + upper[:3] # Note I switched the right part  
print upperNew
```

Then `'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC'` is printed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Silly error in my code:

```
upperNew = upper[:3] + upper[3:]
```

Should be...

```
upperNew = upper[3:] + upper[:3]
```

Thanks thefourtheye et al